# Is there any way to tell if an address has been created on an exchange? (e.g., Coinbase)

Tags: address, exchanges

I am wondering if there is any way to check that a bitcoin address was created on an exchange.

For example, if I want to only interact with (send BTC to) people that have verified their identity (like on Coinbase), is there any way to check that their address is connected to a Coinbase account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible at all. read more [How does Bitcoin work](https://bitcoin.org/en/how-it-works)

Comment: Thanks. So there are no APIs or libraries available or made public by exchanges with lists of wallets created by their site for users?

Comment: No, because it's not possible with Bitcoin since there's no particular sign about how that address created or where. Bitcoin built to be like that. Anonymous.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that about bitcoin but was curious if exchanges made it public somehow through some APIs when they create those wallets. 

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

"Verified" addresses are not something you are likely to see, although could be implemented by trusting a 3rd party (if users choose to opt in).  This isn't really the allure of Bitcoin, so I wouldn't expect such an idea to gain much traction.

Determining if an address belongs to an exchange, however, may be possible using blockchain analysis.  By correlating inputs and outputs of a transaction known to be from an exchange, you may be able to determine with a varying degree off certainty other addresses and transactions that belong to that entity.

Answer (score 0):

Such a verification would require the providing of specific evidence (such as a screen shot, which could still be faked) or a verification by Coinbase themselves.  I wouldn't hold my breath for either of those options, if I were you.